# Multiple filter parameters in the foreign key relation with reduce function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model ToBePosted that has a foreign key to Campaign and Size.

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Size(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class ToBePosted(models.Model):
     campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='to_be_posted_posters')
     size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='to_be_posted_posters')
```

My queryset in views.py:

```
    def get_to_be_posted_queryset_with_filter(self, request):
        filter_params = ToBePostedParameterConverter(request.GET)
        queryset = ToBePosted.objects.all()
        return queryset.filter(filter_params.get_filter())
```

And helpers.py where ToBePostedParameterConverter is located

```
class ParameterConverter:
    # Convert url query params to queryset filter params
    query_patterns = {
        "campaign": 'to_be_posted__campaign__name',
        "size": 'reference__size__name',
    }

    def __init__(self, query_dict):
        self._query_dict = query_dict
        self._filter_params = []
        self._convert()

    def _convert(self):
        for key in self._query_dict:
            for search_key in self._query_dict.getlist(key):
                if query_param := self.query_patterns.get(key):
                    self._filter_params.append(Q(**{query_param: search_key}))

    def get_filter(self):
        if self._filter_params:
            return reduce(operator.or_, self._filter_params)
        return Q()


class ToBePostedParameterConverter(ParameterConverter):
    query_patterns = {
        "campaign": 'campaign__name',
        "size": 'size__name',
    }

    def get_filter(self):
        if self._filter_params:
            return reduce(operator.or_, self._filter_params)
        return Q()
```

The question is:

when I try to get an object Tobeposted with a size of 666 but only associated with campaigns Acamp and Bcamp I get all objects that have a size of 666 regardless of the specified campaigns in the url

***EXAMPLE OF REQUEST URL WITH PARAMETERS:***

**http://localhost:8000/api/v2/posters/get_lookups/?campaign=Acamp&campaign=Bcamp&size=666**

How I can change the code to get only posters that are related to specified campaigns in the url paramters?

I tried to use `and_` operator in reduce function. In this case, it works correctly but  I can't specify more than one campaing in the url

Comment: You want to do something like this `return reduce(operator.and_, [reduce(operator.or_,self._size_filter_params),reduce(operator.or_,self._campaign_filter_params)])`

Comment: Is there a more reusable way to implement this? Because there are some other filter parameters that I have